# Centralize div box to the middle and the inside text, independent of screen size

Tags: html, css, center

I'm trying to make the box to always stay in the center (horizontally and vertically) of the page independent of window browser size. The text that's inside the box should be also in the center of the box it is in.

```css
body{
  background-color: black;
}

.box{
  border-style: solid;
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
  margin: auto;
}

.boxInside{
  border-style: solid;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0px;

/*   align a div vertically within its parent element */
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

p{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="background-color: white;">  
  <div class="boxInside" style="background-color: gray;">
    <div class="boxInside" style="background-color: white;">
      <div class="boxInside" style="background-color: gray;">
        <div class="boxInside" style="background-color: white;">
          <div class="boxInside" style="background-color: gray;">
            <div class="boxInside" style="background-color: white;">
              <div class="boxInside" style="background-color: gray;">
                <div class="boxInside" style="background-color: white;">
                  <div class="boxInside" style="background-color: gray;">
                    <div style="">
                      <p>Testing Display</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add a question? Where should we help you?

Comment: try 
` display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
`
on the parent

Comment: i do want to put the box vertically aligned, so when i open in a full page it is on center, and if i resize window it is still in the vertical and horizontal middle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) for each `div` and aligning in the center horizontally and vertically.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.box {
  border-style: solid;
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
  margin: auto;
}

.boxInside {
  border-style: solid;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0px;
  /*   align a div vertically within its parent element 
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  */
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="background-color: white;">
  <div class="boxInside" style="background-color: gray;">
    <div class="boxInside" style="background-color: white;">
      <div class="boxInside" style="background-color: gray;">
        <div class="boxInside" style="background-color: white;">
          <div class="boxInside" style="background-color: gray;">
            <div class="boxInside" style="background-color: white;">
              <div class="boxInside" style="background-color: gray;">
                <div class="boxInside" style="background-color: white;">
                  <div class="boxInside" style="background-color: gray;">
                    <div style="">
                      <p>Testing Display</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Text is align, but when i open this in full page the boxes arer staying at the top of the page, not in the center, I'm trying to make it vertically on center as well